# Re organizing a JSON database to remove duplicates

Tags: python, json, database, nosql

Right now my JSON database looks like this:

```
[{'srcStationName': 'Central', 'srcStationID': 1, 'dstName': 'Central', 
 'dstID': 1, 'octopusAdultFare': 0, 'octopusStudentFare': 0, 
 'singleAdultFare': 0, 'octopusChildFare': 0, 'octopusElderlyFare': 0, 
 'octopusDisabledFare': 0, 'singleChildFare': 0, 'singleElderlyFare': 0},
 {'srcStationName': 'Central', 'srcStationID': 1, 'dstName': 'Admiralty', 
 'dstID': 2, 'octopusAdultFare': 4.6, 'octopusStudentFare': 3, 
 'singleAdultFare': 5, 'octopusChildFare': 3, 'octopusElderlyFare': 2, 
 'octopusDisabledFare': 2, 'singleChildFare': 3, 'singleElderlyFare': 3},
 {'srcStationName': 'Central', 'srcStationID': 1, 'dstName': 'Tsim Sha Tsui', 
 'dstID': 3, 'octopusAdultFare': 10, 'octopusStudentFare': 5, 
 'singleAdultFare': 11, 'octopusChildFare': 5, 'octopusElderlyFare': 2, 
 'octopusDisabledFare': 2, 'singleChildFare': 5, 'singleElderlyFare': 5},

 {'srcStationName': 'Heng On', 'srcStationID': 101, 'dstName': 'Fortress 
 Hill', 'dstID': 30, 'octopusAdultFare': 21.5, 'octopusStudentFare': 10.7, 
 'singleAdultFare': 24, 'octopusChildFare': 10.7, 'octopusElderlyFare': 2, 
 'octopusDisabledFare': 2, 'singleChildFare': 12, 'singleElderlyFare': 12},
 {'srcStationName': 'Heng On', 'srcStationID': 101, 'dstName': 'North Point', 
 'dstID': 31, 'octopusAdultFare': 21.5, 'octopusStudentFare': 10.7, 
 'singleAdultFare': 24, 'octopusChildFare': 10.7, 'octopusElderlyFare': 2, 
 'octopusDisabledFare': 2, 'singleChildFare': 12, 'singleElderlyFare': 12},
 {'srcStationName': 'Heng On', 'srcStationID': 101, 'dstName': 'Quarry Bay', 
 'dstID': 32, 'octopusAdultFare': 21.5, 'octopusStudentFare': 10.7, 
 'singleAdultFare': 24, 'octopusChildFare': 10.7, 'octopusElderlyFare': 2, 
 'octopusDisabledFare': 2, 'singleChildFare': 12, 'singleElderlyFare': 12}]
```

Since there are the same "srcStations" and multiple "destinations", my desired result is I want to convert to a format like below:

```
{1: {1: {'octopusAdultFare': 0, 'octopusStudentFare': 0, 'octopusChildFare': 
 0, 'octopusElderlyFare': 0, 'octopusDisabledFare': 0, 'singleAdultFare': 0, 
 'singleChildFare': 0, 'singleElderlyFare': 0}, 2: {'octopusAdultFare': 4.6, 
 'octopusStudentFare': 3, 'octopusChildFare': 3, 'octopusElderlyFare': 2, 
 'octopusDisabledFare': 2, 'singleAdultFare': 5, 'singleChildFare': 3, 
 'singleElderlyFare': 3}, 3: {'octopusAdultFare': 10, 'octopusStudentFare': 
 5, 'octopusChildFare': 5, 'octopusElderlyFare': 2, 'octopusDisabledFare': 2, 
 'singleAdultFare': 11, 'singleChildFare': 5, 'singleElderlyFare': 5},

 101: {1: {'octopusAdultFare': 21.5, 'octopusStudentFare': 10.7
 'octopusChildFare': 10.7, 'octopusElderlyFare': 2, 'octopusDisabledFare': 
 2, 'singleAdultFare': 24, 'singleChildFare': 12, 'singleElderlyFare': 12}, 
 2: {'octopusAdultFare': 21.5, 'octopusStudentFare': 10.7, 'octopusChildFare': 
 10.7, 'octopusElderlyFare': 2, 'octopusDisabledFare': 2, 
 'singleAdultFare': 24, 'singleChildFare': 12, 'singleElderlyFare': 12}, 3: {'octopusAdultFare': 
 21.5, 'octopusStudentFare': 10.7, 'octopusChildFare': 10.7, 
 'octopusElderlyFare': 2, 'octopusDisabledFare': 2, 'singleAdultFare': 
 24, 'singleChildFare': 12, 'singleElderlyFare': 12}
}
```

Where the first "1", and the "101" key is the 'srcStationID', and the corresponding Object contains "dstIDs" as keys and their prices. I need help to write a function in python that will do this conversion for me and will write the result to a JSON file. Thank you.

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to layer relational logic on top of a non-relational database. You will almost always have better results going the other way.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it with the following code:

```
newData = []
entities = {}
for entity in data:
    if not entity['srcStationID'] in entities:
        entities[entity['srcStationID']] = {
            entity['dstID'] : {
                'octopusAdultFare' : entity.get('octopusAdultFare'),
                'octopusStudentFare' : entity.get('octopusStudentFare'),
                'octopusChildFare' : entity.get('octopusChildFare'),
                'octopusElderlyFare' : entity.get('octopusElderlyFare'),
                'octopusDisabledFare' : entity.get('octopusDisabledFare'),
                'singleAdultFare' : entity.get('singleAdultFare'),
                'singleChildFare' : entity.get('singleChildFare'),
                'singleElderlyFare' : entity.get('singleElderlyFare')
            }
        }
    else:
        entities[entity['srcStationID']][entity['dstID']] = {
            'octopusAdultFare' : entity.get('octopusAdultFare'),
            'octopusStudentFare' : entity.get('octopusStudentFare'),
            'octopusChildFare' : entity.get('octopusChildFare'),
            'octopusElderlyFare' : entity.get('octopusElderlyFare'),
            'octopusDisabledFare' : entity.get('octopusDisabledFare'),
            'singleAdultFare' : entity.get('singleAdultFare'),
            'singleChildFare' : entity.get('singleChildFare'),
            'singleElderlyFare' : entity.get('singleElderlyFare')
        }
```